# SQL Server calculate percents of values for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a query which return a table something like:

```
Value    Description
--------------------
12       Decription1
43       Decription2
78       Decription3
3        Decription4
6        Decription5
```

My `select` looks like

```
select 
    sum(value), description 
from 
    table 
group by 
    description
```

There are 5 rows and the sum of all 5 rows are 169 which is 100%, now I want to find out how many % is for first row, for second and so on, I know that the formula is for e.g for first row 12*100/169. How to do this in my query.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for your help, all answers are correct, that's why I will mark  like correct the lad2025's answer, and all of you I will vote up. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windowed functions:

```
SELECT *,
    [percentage] = ROUND(100 * 1.0 * value / SUM(value) OVER(), 0)
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/416690)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ value ║ Description ║ Percentage ║
╠═══════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║    12 ║ Decription1 ║          8 ║
║    43 ║ Decription2 ║         30 ║
║    78 ║ Decription3 ║         55 ║
║     3 ║ Decription4 ║          2 ║
║     6 ║ Decription5 ║          4 ║
╚═══════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @total int;
select @total = Sum(Value) from table

select (sum(value) * 100.0)/@total as percentage , description 
    from table 
      group by description`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select description , value,pcnt =  100.*value / (sum(value) over ( )) 
    from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select description, sum(value),
       sum(value) * 100.0 / sum(sum(value)) over () as percentage
from table
group by description;
```